# Writing partial region of downloaded file

Tags: java, file-io, download

I am downloading a file from internet separately. Like 3 regions. Lets say I have to download a file of size 1024kB and i am have set the region as 0-340kB, 341 - 680kB and 681kB - 1024 kB. I have separate thread of each sections. But, the problem i have now is, writing the downloaded file content into a single file.

Since we have 3 threads, each will download the sections which needs to be write in to the file sequentially.

How can I achieve this ?  I thought of having 3 temporary files and write into them. Once all the files written, I have to read file by file and write into a single file. I felt like this is kind of overhead. Is there any other better way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure about this so I'm posting it as a comment, but won't you be able to write at a specified place in the file ? Since you know the size of each part I think you could create a 1024kB blank file, and each thread could write starting at a different index.

Comment: Why would somebody want to have three threads to download a file and substantially increase the overhead?

Comment: Actually, i thought of increasing the file download speed by means of separating the files into sections and download them separately which in turn increase the overall speed. That is the idea behind the logic which i am trying to achieve

Comment: DeadlyJesus, could you please give an example of how to write into different index of file ?

Comment: Use a `RandomAccessFile` and pre-allocate the size with the `setLength()` method. Be aware that a `RandomAccessFile` is NOT threadsafe, so you would have to build your own locking mechanisms around that.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, I am not convinced that this approach will actually improve the download speed.  It may give more consistent download speeds if you are downloading the same file from multiple mirrors, though.

First off, if your file isn't too large, you can buffer all of it before you write it out.  So allocate a buffer that all your threads can access:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[fileSize];
```

Now you create a suitable Thread type:

```
public class WriterThread extends Thread
{
    byte[] buf;
    int write_pos, write_remaining;

    public WriterThread(byte[] buf, int start, int len)
    {
        this.buf = buf;
        this.write_pos = start;
        this.write_remaining = len;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try (Socket s = yourMethodForSettingUpTheSocketConnection();
             InputStream istream = s.getInputStream()) {
            while (this.write_remaining > 0) {
                int read = istream.read(this.buf, this.write_pos, this.write_remaining);
                if (read == -1) error("Not enough data received");
                this.write_remaining -= read;
                this.write_pos += read;
            }
            // otherwise you are done reading your chunk!
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can start as many of these `WriterThread` objects with suitable starts and lengths.  For example, for a file that is 6000 bytes in size:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[6000];
WriterThread t0 = new WriterThread(buf, 0, 3000);
WriterThread t1 = new WriterThread(buf, 3000, 3000);
t0.start();
t1.start();
t0.join();
t1.join();
// check for errors
```

Note the important bit here:  each of the WriterThreads has a referecence to exactly the same buffer, just a different offset that it starts writing at.  Of course you have to make sure that `yourMethodForSettingUpTheSocketConnection` requests data starting at offset `this.write_pos`; how you do that depends on the networking protocol that you use and is beyond what you asked about.

If your file is too big to fit into memory, this approach won't work.  Instead, you'll have to use the (slower) method of first creating a large file and then writing to that.  While I haven't tried that, you should be able to use `java.nio.file.File.newByteChannel()' to set up a suitable`SeekableByteChannel`as your output file.  If you create such a`SeekableByteChannel sbc`, you should then be able to do

```
sbc.location(fileSize - 1); // move to the specified position in the file
sbc.write(java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(1)); // grow the file to the expected final size
```

and then use one distinct `SeekableByteChannel` object per thread, pointing to the same file on disk, and setting the write start location using the `SeekableByteChannel.location(int)` method.  You'll need a temporary `byte[]` around which you can wrap a `ByteBuffer` (via `ByteBuffer.wrap()`), but otherwise the strategy is analogous to the above:

```
thread_local_sbc.location(this.write_pos);
```

and then every `thread_local_sbc.write()` will write to the file starting at `this.write_pos`.